# Can I view the mobile version of Google Calendar on my desktop?

Tags: google-calendar

Do I need to mess around with the user-agent, or is there a less intrusive 'hack'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://www.google.com/calendar/m

Hope this helps.

Comment: Lovely - bookmarked!

Answer (score 4):

You have multiple options available:

<s>**2000's mobile (WAP style)**</s>

Ready to use, just go to https://calendar.google.com/calendar/m

*Edit 2022: Seems to no longer be available and redirects to /gp*

**2010's mobile (iPhone 3 style)**

Ready to use, just go to https://calendar.google.com/calendar/gp

**Embeded widget**

Use this url to configure the widget: https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embedhelper

Then you can use the iframe code to integrate this.

You may also want to just extract the `src` value and HTML entity decode it to use in your browser (Decoder: https://mothereff.in/html-entities)